# Should I include in my CV a conference abstract presented by a collaborator of mine?

Tags: publications, phd, conference, cv

I found some very similar questions, but not clarifying my doubt. I'm a co-author of a research work in space engineering, used to write my M.Sc. thesis, that has been presented at an international conference by my supervisor. She submitted a two pages-conference abstract before presenting, and such a document is now published on the conference website. In spite of it's not a scientific article and I think it has not been published in any journal (not sure of that), I was wondering if I can include it in my CV under a section named "conference presentations". I'm currently modifying my CV before applying for a PhD position, and I want to make it much tailored as possible with PhD topic.

P.s. My name and ORCID is inserted after abstract title.

Comment: Which field are you in? Were you involved in the conference abstract or the presentation?

Comment: @Christian question updated. Sorry for previous missing information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In computer science, especially in the field I work in, such as AI/ML, we have such conferences or workshops where the papers do not get published by any specific publisher but instead get archived by the conference (probably, permanently) on the conference website.

If your name is in the 2-page abstract as an author, you should include it because it is your paper too. It is only that your co-author presented the paper. When I list such a publication in my CV, I would also give a link to the conference website or paper.

Example:

F. Author*, S. Author, "A Story on Moon Landing", *Conference Name*, 20XX; URL: Link here. (2-page abstract; *Presenting author)

Comment: Thanks for answering @Coder! What do you suggest as title of the section under which I will include it?

Comment: I usually list it under: Conference/Workshop Publications.

Comment: Yes, "publications", not "presentations". The latter gives the wrong impression.